# Spring Boot SOAP WebService Integration Test with BasicAuth

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, authorization

I have a SpringBoot SOAP WebService annotated with @RolesAllowed("SOME_ROLE"). The production code works correct, i.e. if I send a SOAP-Request with the header "**Authorization: Basic ENCODED_USERNAME_PASSWORD**", service pass, if this header is not provided, then 401 comes back.

The problem is with Integration Tests. Below is a code snippet:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class MyApplicationIT {
    @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort;

    @Test
    void find() {
        MyServicePortType port = getServicePort();
        port.findResult();
    }

private MyServicePortType getServicePort() {
        final URL wsdlUrl;
        try {
            wsdlUrl = new URL("http", "localhost", randomServerPort, "wsdl/data.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        final MyService service = new MyService (wsdlUrl);
        final QName portName = new QName("some_url", "My_PortTypeSoap11");
        final MyServicePortType port = service.getPort(portName, MyServicePortType .class);
        final Map<String, List<Object>> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", singletonList("Basic " + "ENCODED_USERNAME_PASSWORD"));
        }
        final Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
        // requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "manager_user_and_test_user");
        // requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "secret");
        return port;
    }
}
```

I have tried out both combinations - to put Authorization header `MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS` and to put properties `BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY` and `BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY`.

Both does not work. I always get the following 401 error message.
Once again - only by running Integration Tests.

Is this related to wrong client (port) configuration or something to do with ldap schema used for tests?

```
rg.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.findFragebogen(Unknown Source)
    ...
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: null' when communicating with http://localhost:37248/ws
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1619)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1626)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1571)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using an embedded LDAP for your integration test, this dependency is necessary:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```